# Cannot find bower in Visual Studio 2015 RC Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've installed Visual Studio 2015 RC Community Edition. One of the new features of VS 2015 is the native support for Bower. The problem is I cannot find it anywhere.
I've created multiple Web Application projects but there's no "Dependencies" folder in them.
Is Bower supported in the Community Edition?

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question. The issue was that the ASP.NET 5 tempates where somehow not installed. I reinstalled Visual Studio and those templates appeared. The WebSite template does include support for Bower

Answer (score 0):

I see from the comments that you got the missing templates by reinstalling however it might help to understand that the templates are just a collection of files.  They aren't needed to enable bower support.  You can add a bower.json file to any dnx project (or just use bower from the command line at the project root).  Bower is installed by the Visual Studio installer.

This is a nice change in vision by Microsoft.  Instead of using other tech and then changing it in some incompatible way they are just adopting it as-is.  This means that bower in visual studio is the same bower used by the entire rest of the web development community.

All the "visual changes" in the IDE are Visual Studio executing standard bower commands on the command line.  The dependencies pseudo-folders (bower is actually mapped to /bower-components) are IDE visual effects to make it similar to existing developers but behind the scenes standard bower is being used.

You can do it all by executing bower commands on the command line (and some may even prefer to do that).  For those who don't Visual studio is watching the bower.json for changes then passing the appropriate command to Bower.

Here is an example to illustrate it.  In a new or existing dnx project add `"angular": "1.3.15"` to your bower.json file and save it.  Visual studio will execute `bower install angular#1.3.15`.  You can verify this by checking the output window.   In the solution explorer right click on Bower (under dependencies) and select `Open In File Explorer`.  Notice the folder is /bower-components off project root (hidden by VS IDE) and the angular package is here. In the Solution Explorer right click on angular(1.3.15) and select `Uninstall package`.  Visual studio runs the command `bower uninstall angular`.

Comment: just to add, you **can** use bower with non-dnx projects. like mvc5

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've been using Bower in Visual Studio through the NuGet package but since v2015 has native support I wanted to give it a try.
So, you are saying that I should be able to use Bower on ASP.NET 4.6 templates?

Comment: @HyperD.  It depends on what you mean "use".  You certainly can use bower in any project as bower is just a standalone command line tool.  VS doesn't have the IDE level helper integration for non DNX projects.  So there is no dependency updates and auto file change checking within the IDE but you could either use command shell or script it up yourself.  I see no technical reason why VS doesn't provide the same support for non DNX projects so it could be added.  I would send Microsoft some feedback if it is something you want.